# How to upgrade nginx from 1.2 to 1.6 on debian 7

Tags: nginx, upgrade

I've looked through the whole web but couldn't find anything ! 

I modified `sources.list` but the server is tuck to nginx 1.2 , I don't know what to do please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add wheezy-backports to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
```

and then on a console:

```
aptitude update
aptitude -t wheezy-backports install nginx
```

Comment: Be sure to learn about [backports](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports) before starting to use them.